# Multiple enum initialization

Tags: java, enums

Been trying to build up a class which i want to keep more or less static, so i can select different elements by categories as:
MyClass.CategoryOne.ELEMENTONE

What i built to achieve this is

```
public class ElementClass {
public static List<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<Element>();

public enum Animals {
    DOG(new Dog()),
    CAT(new Cat());

    private Animal element;

    private Animals (Animal element) {
        this.element= element;

        addToList(element);
    }

    public Animal getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}

public enum Plants {
    TREE(new Tree());
    BUSH(new Bush());

    private Plant element;

    private Plants (Plant element) {
        this.element= element;

        addToList(element);
    }

    public Plant getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}

public enum Buildings {
    FENCE(new Fence()),
    BRIDGE(new Bridge()),

    private Building element;

    private Buildings(Building element) {
        this.entity = element;

        addToList(element);
    }

    public Building getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}

private static void addToList(Element element) {
    if (!elementList.contains(element)) {
        elementList.add(element);
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that it's not initialized completely (at some point in the code, the Plants enum is not added to the list, while the rest is).

I could "patch" that up using:

```
private static ElementClass instance = new ElementClass ();

private ElementClass () {
    ElementClass.Animals.values();
    ElementClass.Plants.values();
    ElementClass.Buildings.values();
}

public static ElementClass getInstance() {return instance;}
```

And calling the instance early, but i was wondering.. Is there a way to do it without having to add the values call without other objective? I imagine that my approach is not the best, but i don't know other approach that allows me to access each element this way (ElementClass.Animals.DOG  for example).

If the approach is not too bad, is there a way to go through all the enums when the class starts? or a way to add it in a for loop (i don't know if getClass().getFields() could help in that, or if i can cast the field to enum to take the values).

Comment: _at some point in the code_ Show us **that** code.

Comment: How are you subclassing enums? I don't think that is possible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This code has several problems.

1. It uses a non-final static field. That is almost always a code smell. This list should be final: any code can replace the list by another one
2. The list is modifiable. Any code can remove elements from the list, sort it, or add elements to the list. It should be wrapped in an unmodifiable view
3. The list is populated lazily, when each of the enum is loaded by the class loader. It seems you want it loaded eagerly. This also causes thread-safety issues.
4. the list is populated by an enum constructors. That shouldn't be done there.

My advice, remove the addToList calls from the constructor, and use something like the following:

```
public static final List<Element> ELEMENT_LIST = createList();

private static List<Element> createList() {
    List<Element> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<HasElement> enumValues = new ArrayList<>();
    enumValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(Animal.values));
    enumValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(Plant.values));
    ...
    for (HasElement hasElement : enumValues) {
        result.add(hasElement.getElement());
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(result);

}

interface HasElement {
    Element getElement();
}

public enum Animals implements HasElement {
    DOG(new Dog()),
    CAT(new Cat());

    private Animal element;

    private Animals (Animal element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public Animal getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just skipping enums all together and using a static inner class? For example:

```
public final class ElementClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ElementClass.Animal.DOG.makeSound();
    ElementClass.Animal.CAT.makeSound();
}


public static abstract class Animal {
    public static Animal DOG = new Dog();
    public static Animal CAT = new Cat();

    public abstract void makeSound();
  }

}

// NOTE: Put in separate file if it needs to be accessible outside package. 
final class Dog extends ElementClass.Animal {

    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("WOOF!");
    }
}

final class Cat extends ElementClass.Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("MEOW!");
    }

}
```

This also avoids the two anti-patterns of having a a static collection and a publicly accessible collection.

You didn't specify that the elements of any given category needed to be iteratble, so I did not include that as a requirement, only that you can address them as you specified.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that class initialization is deferred until first usage.

You might use the enum classes themselves, in some form.

```
public class ElementClass {

    public static List<Class<Enum<?>>> enumClasses() {
        List<Class<Enum<?>>> clazzes = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(clazzes,
            Animals.class, Plants.class, Buildings.class);
        return clazzes;
    }
```

Manually adding every class seems a minor overhead.

And then:

```
for (Class<Enum<?>> clazz : ElementClass.enumClasses()) {
     // Getting a single value:
     Object dog = Enum.valueOf(clazz, "DOG");

     // Getting all values:
     Object[] all = clazz.getEnumConstants();
}
```